# How long after I close my Microsoft account will all my data be deleted from their backups?

Tags: privacy, microsoft-account

Been trying to find a definitive answer for awhile in various places with no luck.

If a MS account has been deleted, and is past the 60-day grace period to cancel deletion, how long before the data is deleted from the server and the offline backups?

Answer (score 1):

Only Microsoft can answer the exact time period.

As per my knowledge after 60 days they delete all your data from the sever. Some data might take few more days or weeks to get clear from the server and backups. But after 60 days you will not be able to access any application through that account.